# How to add the global keyword to Metadata.xml for Xamarin jar binding?

Tags: android, paypal, binding, jar, xamarin

I am attempting to bind a jar file to a Xamarin bindings project. For a particular field, the global keyword needs to be used in order to avoid ambiguity between 2 namespaces (com.paypal.android & android.widget).

```
Error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Widget' does not exist in the namespace 'Com.Paypal.Android'. Are you missing an assembly reference?
```

Xamarin is smart enough to include the global keywords within the field's getter and setter; unfortunately, Xamarin isn't smart enough to to include it in the field's type:

```
public IList<Android.Widget.TextView> C {
```

When I alter the code itself, it gets overwritten when I rebuild the project. I believe I need to add the global keyword inside the Metadata.xml (although, I'm not quite sure how).

I've attempted to add the following in order to change the return type:

```
<attr path="/api/package[@name='com.paypal.android.sdk']/class[@name='cD']/field[@name='c']" name="managedReturn"> NOT SURE WHAT GOES HERE </attr>
```

[image]

Comment: You can edit the generated file and use ```global::Android.Widget.TextView``` to avoid namespace conflicts

Comment: @GuilhermeTorresCastro yes, but if you ever need to rebuild the project, the edit will be removed.